# R -- unembedding a list of lists from a data.frame column

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns, nested-lists

I have a data.frame with two columns that looks like this:

```
sid        calibration
sid201     [['left', '37.1', '18.9', '0.0', '0.9\xb0', '0.4\xb0'], ['right', '42.2', '24.0', '0.0', '1.0\xb0', '0.6\xb0']]
sid202     [['left', '7.4', '13.6', '0.0', '0.2\xb0', '0.3\xb0'], ['right', '14.6', '15.1', '0.0', '0.3\xb0', '0.4\xb0']]
```

and so on for each row.

The problem I am having is figuring out how to extract the info I need from the "calibration" column.

I would like to parse the "calibration" factor into two rows with "left" and "right" being levels of a new factor "eye", and each of the other 5 elements being assigned to its own column -- lets simply say columns a:e.

Comment: Imo -- when I try to follow your example I get stuck creating the df -- the error message is:  Error in df$sid : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Answer (score 0):

If the data is stored as you say, you might try the following for a data.frame named df:

```
# stack the data
dfStacked <- data.frame("sid"=c(df$sid, df$sid), 
             "calibration"=c(sapply(df$calibration, function(i) c(i[[1]])),
                             sapply(df$calibration, function(i) c(i[[2]]))))
# split the data vectors
calibList <- strsplit(dfStacked$calibration, split=", ")

# put the results into a data.frame, loops through variables in outer loop
# loops through observations in inner row to get variables
results <- as.data.frame(sapply(1:5, 
          function(element) cbind(sapply(calibList, function(row) c(row[[i]])))))
# add to dataset
dfDone <- cbind(dfStacked$sid, results)
```